# How to display .ptm file in my WP site without JAVA

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I created a wordpress site which displays *Polynomial Texture Map* (.ptm) using [Java PTM viewer](http://rti.im/tools/) developed by **Hembo Pagi**. See [here](http://rti.im/tools/wp-plugin/).

It uses *WP shortcodes*, so to embed my file by just write:

```
[rti src="_filename.ptm_" width="_width_" height="_height_"]
```

But this plugin uses *JAVA* applet and there is the limitation that *JAVA* must be installed on viewer machine.

Is there any other way to accomplish this without *JAVA* render `.ptm` file?

Comment: Please remove direct download link and add link to page where you can download it. It's very unpleasant to hunt it down from computer if you accidentally downloaded it - there's no warning of any kind.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to display that file type without a browser extension of some kind and JAVA is going to be you best bet. If you want something to display I'd suggest exporting a .png or .jpg.